# Can not read fields of NodeList obtained from documents.getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am having a weird issue with NodeList. I can print NodeList object on the console and showing it has length 1. However, if I tried to get any elements from the NodeList by using .item(0) or [0], it ends up with either null or undefined. I've checked NodeList documents and pretty sure I am reading element correctly. Can anyone explain why?

I am coding under React, but I think this should be pure JavaScript issue. Here is the issue I recreated in code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-lichterman-u0mfz?file=/src/App.js
It is a little bit messy but you can see from top of console that only Nodelist is printed but node from the list is null.

[image]

[image]

The goal is to retrieve value of the DOM element by name reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply

For ex:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style
```

In your case:

```
document.getElementsByName('form_type')[0].style
```

Comment: That's what I thought should work, but I got 'Cannot read property 'style' of undefined'.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing wrong. I tried on codepen seems like working fine for me: https://codepen.io/acool9531/pen/bGpqjLR

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-lichterman-u0mfz?file=/src/App.js

Here is the CodeSandbox. It is a little bit messy since I need to take the whole section out from the big project. But you can see that I can only print the nodelist but not the node from the nodelist in the top of console